# Remove what's in one list from the other list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have two lists which contain a bunch of elements of the same type:

```
std::list<Part> allParts = step.getSubParts();
std::list<Part> toRemove;
for (Part part : allParts)
{
    for (Part partTwo : allParts) {
        if (part.getEdges() == partTwo.getEdges())
            if (part.getFaces() == partTwo.getFaces())
                if (part.getShells() == partTwo.getShells())
                    if (part.getVertices() == partTwo.getVertices())
                        if (part.getWires() == partTwo.getWires())
                        {
                            part.addAmount(1);
                            toRemove.push_back(partTwo);
                        }

    }
}
```

I have tried iterating through both and remove from the one but I'm constantly getting the `list iterators are incompatible` error. This is my latest attempt:

```
std::list<Part>::iterator it;
for (it = step.getSubParts().begin(); it != step.getSubParts().end();)
{
    std::list<Part>::iterator i;
    for (i = toRemove.begin(); i != toRemove.end();)
    {
        if (it->getEdges() == i->getEdges())
            if (it->getFaces() == i->getFaces())
                if (it->getShells() == i->getShells())
                    if (it->getVertices() == i->getVertices())
                        if (it->getWires() == i->getWires())
                        {
                            it = step.getSubParts().erase(it);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            it++;
                        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Everything I have tried doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: FYI: You can overload the `operator==` of `Part` to shorten your comparisons.

Comment: Can you sort list ? Then [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)/[std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) might help.

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicates from a list? The first code piece you provided suggests so. If so, provide comparison funcion object to `std::sort`, and then use: `std::unique` `std::erase`.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider `remove_if` or `erase_if` rather than doing your own erase with the hazard of making `iterator` invalid within a loop.

By the way, you should write predicate like:

```
if (it->getEdges() == i->getEdges() &&
    it->getFaces() == i->getFaces() &&
    it->getShells() == i->getShells() &&
    it->getVertices() == i->getVertices() &&
    it->getWires() == i->getWires()) {
    // do something
}
```

Your code makes people difficult to understand your purpose(at least me).

[erase and erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase2)

Comment: Sorry. Because I didn't want to read anymore after reading the first piece of code. It seems that `toRemove` will equal `allParts` in all cases.

Comment: @tigertang you're right and that's wrong which I will change but that wasn't the problem, the problem is that I can't nest two loops and remove something from onr list. I will try remove_if/erase_if

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be a good idea to follow the Don't Repeat Yourself principle and write a comparison function for future use:

```
    auto compare_parts = [](const Part& p1, const Part& p2) -> bool {
        return ( (p1.getEdges() == p2.getEdges())
             and (p1.getFaces() == p2.getFaces())
             and (p1.getShells() == p2.getShells())
             and (p1.getVertices() == p2.getVertices())
             and (p1.getWires() == p2.getWires()) );
    }
```

You would rewrite the first cycle using it and see how much more simple it looks.

Then why not use c++ built-in methods to erase the elements from the list using the function we wrote? This uses new feature in c++ called [binding parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) that would aid us here

```
    #include <functional>
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    for (auto&& badPart : toRemove) {
        auto isBad = std::bind(compare_parts, badPart, _1);
        step.getSubParts().remove_if(isBad);
    }
```

And that's how you remove special entries from the list.

Comment: You can even factorize `compare_parts` to something like `return as_tuple(p1) == as_tuple(p2);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 What is `as_tuple`? Did you mean `std::forward_as_tuple`?

Comment: @DanielLangr: No, I meant a custom function `auto as_tuple(const Part& p) { return std::tie(p.getEdges(), /*..*/ , p.getWires()); }` (Use the more appropriate between `std::tie`/`std::make_tuple`/`std::forward_as_tuple` :-) ).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, will try if the other answer doesn't work. I'm very new to c++ but have experience in other languages, I know am not to repeat myself but I wasn't going for clean code here just wanted to get something that actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be:

#### 1. Implement equality operator for the class `Part`

You can either put it inside or outside the class, it would look like this if you implement it as an external function

```
inline bool operator==(const Part& lhs, const Part& rhs) {
    return lhs.getEdges() == rhs.getEdges() &&
    lhs.getFaces() == rhs.getFaces() &&
    lhs.getShells() == rhs.getShells() &&
    lhs.getVertices() == rhs.getVertices() &&
    lhs.getWires() == rhs.getWires();
}
```

#### 2. Implement the loop, I would recommend using iterators

This is just one way of doing it

```
if (allParts.size() > 1) {
    for(auto partIt = std::begin(allParts); partIt != std::end(allParts); partIt++) {
        for(auto partIt2 = std::next(partIt); partIt2 != std::end(allParts);) { // Manual increasing because we erase stuff
            if(*partIt == *partIt2) { // Previously implemented equility operator
                partIt->AddAmount(1);
                partIt2 = allParts.erase(partIt2); // If erase, use the returned iterator as your next `Part`
            } else {
                partIt2++; // Only increment if nothing was erased (when you erase iterators get invalidated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I implement the operator, inside the class or outside the class doesn't matter where I put it I'm getting errors. Sorry, I'm new to c++ and this all is very frustrating.

Comment: Put it after the class, outside of it. Copy the code I sent you.